# Close modal when href button stop request

Tags: jquery, http, bootstrap-modal

From my mentioned title above, do anyone know how to make a modal bootstrap close when button `<a class='btn btn-success' href='myproject.com/api/payout.xls?worker='19'>download commission</a>` inside modal stop request ?

for now when I clicked the button download commission, it is like pending for 15 seconds to download that file. and after around 15 seconds, I can see download file has been download in my browser [refer picture below]. but the issue is my modal do not close. How to do it?

thanks, faizal

[image]

Comment: call a function for on click of anchor tag, will work in other waym to close modal here is the code    $('#modal').modal('toggle');

Answer (score 0):

Bind click event for the  tag and try the following code to close the modal:

```
$(function () {
   $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```